# How to decline "Trump"?

Tags: власні-назви, відмінювання

> **This question also has been asked here (in Ukrainian):**
>   *[Як правильно написати в заяві "директору" чи "директорові"?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/2937)*

There are somewhat ambiguous [declension rules](http://www.dilovamova.com/index.php?page=4&dmua=19&tdmua=%D1%EA%EB%E0%E4%ED%B3-%E2%E8%EF%E0%E4%EA%E8-%E2%B3%E4%EC%B3%ED%FE%E2%E0%ED%ED%FF-%EF%F0%B3%E7%E2%E8%F9&list=1) of foreign proper names in Dative (and, to some extent, Locative) case.

For example Nominative *Trump*: would the Dative be *Трампу* or *Трампові*?

**Update.** AFAIU, both variants are *formally* allowed (I have no proofs, however).
However, the latter one `-ові` seems to be less used in mass media.
I'm trying to figure out whether or not both variants are, indeed, *grammatical*.

---

**Note 1**. I'm not asking about Noun-based Possessive Adjectives like [*Трампові лестощі*](http://www.eurointegration.com.ua/news/2016/10/18/7056084/).

**Note 2**. I'm pretty certain that the Dative for *Дональд* ("Donald") can be either *Дональду* or *Дональдові*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a declension rule ([e.g. § 49 here](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil2.htm)) for **singular masculine nouns ending with hard consonant** which can be classified as [hard group of 2<sup>nd</sup> declension](http://www.mova.club/ukrainian/grammar/morphology/morphology.8.html). `-ові` and `-y` endings can be equaly used to form dative.

However, when several nouns from hard group of 2<sup>nd</sup> declension go **in a row** then `-ові` is used for first to form dative and `-у` for rest of them 'to avoid monotony'. Usually this situation appears with full names which usualy do not contain to many words to cause `-y` ending monotony.

In the media word `Трамп` is often used after word *Дональд*. In other words *Дональд Трамп* is declined to dative more often then just *Трамп*. Тhis fact reduces chances of *Трампові* appearance.