# Як правильно написати в заяві "директору" чи "директорові"?

Tags: правопис, орфографія, стилістика

> **Це запитання також має відповідь (англійською):**
>   *[How to decline "Trump"?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/235)*

Дуже часто в документах можна зустріти різні варіації вживання посади чи прізвища того, кому адресується заява. Постає питання, який з варіантів правильний? "Директорові" чи "директору"? "Гнатюкові Р.Г." чи "Гнатюку Р.Г."?

Comment: привіт. завітайте до чату, бітте, може, проясните нам трохи, звідки ви всі прилетіли на сайт? ми дуже тішимося, в разі чого, що ви залетіли)
https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53202/ukrainian-language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Закінчення давального (а також місцевого) відмінку однини **-у/-ю** та **-ові/-еві/-єві** рівноправні. Як правило, коли кілька іменників поспіль стоять в давальному чи місцевому відмінку однини, то перш іменник отримує **-ові**, а решта **-у**:

> Директорові Гнатюку Роману Григоровичу

Можна написати й «Директору Гнатюку Р. Г.», та тоді ми нехтуємо милозвучністю, яка є одним із важливих чинників у нашій мові. Теж через милозвучність два слова поспіль із закінченням **-ові/-еві/-єві** не вживаються.

Коли ж іменник лише один, то можна вживати будь-яке з цих двох закінчень, на ваш вибір.

Всі іменники, які можуть мати закінчення **-ові/-еві/-єві**, можна вживати і з закінченням **-у/-ю**, та є певні іменники, які вживаються лише із **-у/-ю**. Це іменники чоловічого роду на **-ів, -їв, -ов, -ея, -єв, -ин, -ін, -їн**, хоча в прізвищах на **-ин, -ін, -їн** допускається й **-ові/-еві/-єві** (Пушкінові):

> Ки́їв — Ки́єву, Колгу́єв — Колгу́єву, Лебеди́н — Лебедину́, Львів — Льво́ву, Ма́монтов — Ма́монтову, о́стрів — о́строву, Пу́шкін — Пу́шкіну, рів — ро́ву, Ха́рків — Ха́ркову.

• [Правила](https://r2u.org.ua/pravopys/pravXXI/57.html)

• [Популярно](http://www.mova.info/article.aspx?l1=118&DID=367)